# SQL Server 2014 SSAS data mining server not running in multidimensional mode error

Tags: sql-server, build, ssas

I am trying to build a basic data mining project in visual studio 2015 (using template Analysis Services Multidimensional and Data Mining Project). I have set up a data source on my localhost ( I have not created a DB myself, but only used the one visual studio offered me) and created a mining structure, but every time I try to build and launch my project an error occurs:

```
You cannot deploy the model because the localhost deployment server is not running in multidimensional mode.            0
```

I Understand the error, but I dont know to fix this error. Can I change a DB setting or have to create a new DB?
I am just trying to learn data mining basics and a few pointers how to fix this error would be welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 possible ways to fix this, 1 is the recommended way and the other one a hack.

the best way is to uninstall SQL Server analysis services only and then reinstall it again in multidimensional mode instead tabular (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143412(v=sql.120).aspx )

The "hack" way is to change the *.ini file, not recommended though!
http://cathydumas.com/2012/04/23/changing-an-analysis-services-instance-to-tabular-mode/